# Partially Correct Frequency Detection in Python

Tags: python, audio, signals, frequency

I have found an algorithm that uses auto correlation and parabolic interpolation to estimate the frequency of an audio signal.

```
# correct the signal.
auto = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(signal, signal[::-1], mode='full')
auto = auto[len(auto)/2:]

# find the first minimum point in the signal.
difference = numpy.diff(auto)
start = matplotlib.mlab.find(difference > 0)[0]

# find the peak from that position.
peak = numpy.argmax(auto[start:]) + start
# calculate the period using parabolic interpolation.
period = 1/2.0 * (auto[peak-1] - auto[peak+1]) / (auto[peak-1] - 2 * auto[peak] + auto[peak+1]) + peak
frequency = sample_rate / period
```

I know the range of human hearing is *20Hz* to *20kHz*. With a sample rate *44100Hz*, I can write and read *22049Hz* accurately. However, the algorithm mistakes some of the frequencies.

Given a signal of *840Hz*, it reads *420Hz*. At *20000Hz*, the algorithm calculates *512Hz*. The algorithm oscillates between accurate estimations and returning the incorrect frequency.

I do not have much knowledge about signal processing.

Comment: Is your signal pure (simulated) or is it a real (noisy) measurement?

Comment: The signals are pure. I use the Python wave module to write the signals. @JulienBernu

Comment: I've never heard of this technique (but I'm not an expert) and a quick search seems to indicate it is mostly used to uncover the 'hidden' fundamental frequency of composite waves, which could somehow explain how you could go from 840 to 420? If I had the same goal, working with pure sinewaves, I'd simply take the fft of the signal itself and look for the peak...

Comment: I'm no expert either. I've read about FFT on wolfram alpha and wiki but still do not have a firm understanding of what happens. Could you explain the approach you've mentioned? @JulienBernu

Comment: FFT stands for Fast Fourier Transform. The Fast part just refers to a clever computing trick to make things... fast. If you search for FFT you'll mostly get results for that computing trick, which is irrelevant to you (as a start). Just search for Fourier Transform to see how it is linked to spectrum analysis. It is reasonably advance math and not to be answered shortly here... For a 2 word answer: the FT of a sinewave exhibits a clear peak at the frequency of your sine (within sampling rate scaling).

Comment: Interesting maths. I found an implementation that uses the algorithm you've described. From what I understand, the peak of the Fourier Transform is the frequency? @JulienBernu

Answer (score 0):

If you want to  estimate the frequency of a pure, simulated signal, the Fourier Transform perfectly fits your needs.

```
import numpy as np

SAMPLE_RATE = 48000
FREQUENCY = 840.0

# simulated pure signal
t = np.linspace(0, 1, SAMPLE_RATE)
signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * FREQUENCY * t)

# compute the magnitude of the Fourier Transform and its corresponding frequency values
freq_magnitudes = np.abs(np.fft.fft(signal))
freq_values = np.fft.fftfreq(SAMPLE_RATE, 1/SAMPLE_RATE)

# find the max. magnitude
max_positive_freq_idx = np.argmax(freq_magnitudes[:SAMPLE_RATE//2 + 1])

print(freq_values[max_positive_freq_idx]) # 840.0
```

If you are not familiar with the Fourier Transform, e.g. have a look at chapter 8 of Steven Smiths [*The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing*](http://www.dspguide.com/ch8.htm).